# How can I glide without transforming into Super Knuckles?

Tags: sonic-mania

Ever since getting all 7 Chaos Emeralds in Sonic Mania, I've had the issue of accidentally transforming into Super Knuckles nearly every stage.

Both Knuckles' glide and the Super Knuckles transformation are activated by pressing the jump button while in midair. This has made it impossible for me to use his glide ability without transforming if I have more than 50 rings.

Is there a way for me to disable the Super transformations so I can use Knuckles' glide again?

Comment: Man, they should've added an option to transform by pressing some other unrelated button, just like in Sonic 4 where a button is reserved specifically for this action. Controllers now have many buttons available and 2D Sonic games never had that many actions.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna [It appears that a separate transform button will be added in an upcoming patch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317415/181240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sonic Mania's developer Christian Whitehead has confirmed that a separate transformation button will be added in an upcoming patch.

The PC version of Sonic Mania includes a separate button for super transformations.

While this option is currently not available on PS4, Xbox One, or Nintendo Switch, developer Christian Whitehead has confirmed that this feature [will be added sometime in the future](https://twitter.com/CFWhitehead/status/902411716872376320).

[image]

Comment: You wonder how this made it past QA.  It's such an obvious problem if they only played the game.

Comment: @Nelson It was likely a holdover from the classic series. I believe the only games with dedicated super buttons were Sonic 4 and Genererations.

Comment: @Nelson it's an oversight, but even having to push jump again was a big improvement from Sonic 2 to Sonic 3 - in Sonic 2 any jump starts Super, not just a second button press.

Comment: @Stevoisiak - did this feature end up getting added to non-Steam versions of the game?